# Assign a new socket to client after receving request from 8080 in server code

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client-server, tcp

C Language TCP server/client.. I want to assign a new socket for a particular client which requested my server from 8080 lets say the new socket is 8081 to get further request, and want to free the previous socket(8080) so that the other clients will request my server from 8080. is there any way of doing it in C language. (OS Ubuntu) Thanks

Comment: You don't need to do that. Multiple clients can connect to the same port at the same time (and maintain independent sockets).

Comment: like  clients continuously sending message to the same port, will this work?

Comment: I want to manage a thread per client

Comment: Think about all the web servers and proxies out there. They all use a single port.

Comment: I know that. this is not a web server. in web-server server make the child process. In this I don't think same port will be enough

Comment: launch each new client socket in its own thread.  This will allow the OS to manage communication from each client socket to the server (i.e., only one thread is given a slice of time at any one time)

Comment: Look ***[here](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/textcode.html)*** for an example of a quick google search.  There are many pages to look at here.

Comment: @Ateeq: not all webservers have a new process for _every_ client. That would not scale well. I repeat, you don't need to do that. Study example TCP client/server examples more. A new socket per client (like some modes of FTP) is actually really bad since it's very hard to firewall or proxy properly. Don't do that.

Comment: Actually it is requirement of the problem statement I need to manage 5 clients or threads on 5 different ports but I want every client to request on 8080 port then my server assign it a new port internally without notifying client and the communication continues.

Comment: The "without notifying the client" part is simply not feasible. The client needs to connect back to that second port. So it needs to know the port number. And the firewalls in between need to have that port open.

Comment: @Ateeq That's not how TCP works. If you're using TCP, you cannot do that, you would need to tell the client to disconnect the current TCP session, and tell it to connect to another port (e.g. 8081). You cannot move an existing TCP connection to another port.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is incorrect. You can't do this even if you wanted to. The way that TCP sockets work is that accept() gives you a new socket for the incoming client connection, on the same port you are listening to. That's all you need and it's all you can get. You can't 'allocate a new socket' to the client on a new port without engaging in another TCP handshake with him, which would be nothing but a complete waste of time when you already have a connection to him. This does not preclude another connection bring accepted while this one is open. You need to read a TCP Sockets networking tutorial.

Comment: I know that but I asked may be there is a way that I don't know. Well thanks for you reply.

Comment: If you knew everything in this answer you wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: O Come on. I said I know that the client have to send again a request on other port but may be there is a way internally to switch the ports.

Comment: Come off it yourself. You didn't say that at all. You just said 'I know that'.

Comment: Well I mean that :) and there is nothing harm in asking what you want. And my problem statement is correct it is what I wanted but unfortunately it is not possible thats all.

Comment: If your 'problem statement' just consists of 'what [you] wanted' it isn't a problem statement at all, just your own personal preference. A problem statement comes from somewhere else, such as a specification you have been provided to implement. You can't dignify your own uninformed preferences as problem statements, sorry. It's just a misleading use of language.

Answer (score -1):

Mat and EJP have said the pertinent things above, but I thought it might help others to describe the situation more verbosely.

A TCP/IP connection is identified by a four-tuple: *target IP address*, *target TCP port number*, *source IP address*, and *source TCP port number*. The kernel will keep track of established connections based on these four things. A single server port (and IP address) can be connected to thousands of clients at the same time, limited in practice only by the resources available.

When you have a listening TCP socket, it is bound to some IP address (or wildcard address) and TCP port. Such a socket does not receive data, only new connections. When `accept()` is called, the server notes the new four-tuple of the connection, and hands off the file descriptor that represents that connection (as the `accept()` return value). The original socket is free to accept new connections. Heck, you can even have more than one thread accepting new connections if you want to, although establishing new connections in Linux is so fast you shouldn't bother; it's just too insignificant to worry about.

If establishing the connection at application level is resource-intensive -- this is true for for example encrypted connections, where agreeing to an encryption scheme and preparing the data structures needed takes typically several orders of magnitude more CPU resources than a simple TCP connection --, then it is natural to wish to avoid that overhead. Let's assume this is the point in OP's question: to avoid unnecessary application-level connection establishment when a recent client needs another connection.

The preferred solution is connection multiplexing. Simply put, the application-level protocol is designed to allow multiple data streams via a single TCP connection.

The OP noted that it would be necessary/preferable to keep the existing application protocol intact, i.e. that the optimization should be completely on the server side, transparent to the clients.

This turns the recommended solution to a completely new direction. We should not talk about application protocols, but how to efficiently implement the existing one.

Before we get to that, let's take a small detour.

Technically, it is possible to use the kernel packet filtering facilities to modify incoming packets to use a different port based on the source IP address, redirecting requests from specific IP addresses to separate ports, and making those separate ports otherwise inaccessible. Technically possible, but quite complex to implement, and with very questionable benefits.

So, let's ignore the direction OP assumed would bring the desired benefits, and look at the alternatives. Or, actually, the common approach used.

Structurally, your application has
 - A piece of code accepting new connections
 - A piece of code establishing the application-level resources needed for that connection
 - A piece of code doing the communication with the client (serving the response to the client, per the client's request)

There is no reason for these three pieces to be consecutive, or even part of the same code flow. Use data structures to your advantage.

Instead of treating new incoming connections (`accept()`ed) as equal, they can be simply thrown into separate pools based on their source IP addresses. (Or, if you are up to it, have a data structure which clusters source IP addresses together, but otherwise keeps them in the order they were received.)

Whenever a worker completes a request by a client, it checks if that same client has new incoming connections. If yes, it can avoid most if not all of the application-level connection establishment by checking that the new connection matches the application-level parameters of the old one. (You see, it is possible that even if the source IP address is the same, it could be a completely different client, for example if the clients are under the same VPN or NATted subnet.)

There are quite a few warts to take care of, for example how to keep the priorities, and avoid starving new IP addresses if known clients try to hog the service.

For protocols like HTTP, where the client sends the request information as soon as the server accepts the connection, there is an even better pattern to apply: instead of connection pools, have *request pools*. A single thread or a thread pool can receive the requests (they may span multiple packets in most protocols), without acting on them; only detecting when the request itself is complete. (A careful server will limit the number of pending requests, and the number of incomplete request, to avoid vulnerability to DOS.)

When the requests are complete, they are grouped, so that the same "worker" who serves one request, can serve another similar request with minimal overhead. Again, some careful thought is needed to avoid the situation where a prolific client hogs the server resources by sending a lot of requests, but it's nothing some careful thought and testing won't resolve.

One question remains:

Do you need to do this?

I'd wager you do not. Apache, which is one of the best HTTP servers, does not do any of the above. The performance benefits are not considered worth the extra code complexity. Could you write a new HTTP server (or a server for whatever protocol you're working with), and use a scheme similar to above, to make sure you can use your hardware as efficiently as possible? Sure. You don't even need to be a wizard, just do some research and careful planning, and avoid getting caught in minute details, keeping the big picture in mind at all times.

I firmly believe that code maintainability and security is more important than efficiency, especially when writing an initial implementation. The information gained from the first implementation has thus far *always* changed how I perceive the actual "problem"; similar to opening new eyes. It has always been worth it to create a robust, easy to develop and maintain, but not necessarily terribly efficient implementation, for the first generation. If there is someone willing to support the development of the next generation, you not only have the first generation implementation to compare (and verify and debug) against, but also all the practical knowledge gained.

That is also the reason old hands warn so often against *premature optimization*. In short, you end up optimizing resource waste and personal pain, not the implementation you're developing.

If I may, I'd recommend the OP back up a few steps, and actually describe what they intend to implement, what the observed problem with the implementation is, and suggestions on how to fix and avoid the problem. The current question is like asking how to better freeze a banana, as it keeps shattering when you hammer nails with it.

Comment: Of course he doesn't 'need to do this'. He *can't* do this within the constraints specified. Accepting an SSL connection has no more overhead than accepting a plaintext connection: you just call accept() and start a thread. *That thread* then has to engage in the SSL handshake, but it has zero impact on the accepting thread. There's a lot of waffle here frankly. -1

Comment: @EJP: Wrong. SSL handshake is part of the application-level connection establishment I described. And he definitely can do this, if he were to use the kernel iptables functionality to do it, it just makes no sense to do so. Thanks for the -1, though; pity it is because you fail to understand what you read. I probably should have kept it shorter to help with that.

Comment: *Of course* SSL connection establishment is part of the application-level connection establishment. I haven't said otherwise. My point is explicitly that it doesn't have to take place in the accepting thread.

Comment: @EJP: It took you two and a half years to respond to that comment? And even then you had to pick out additional constraints out of thin air? The question has no references to threads. You downvoted my answer because you know your own argument cannot stand any scrutiny. If you had any valid points, I'd be happy to discuss those. If you want to go really in depth, my profile has my contact information. However, I'm only interested in matters with practical relevance, not word games or social one-upmanship; I find those infantile.